# Optimizing multiplication of elements 2^x-1

Tags: c, simd, avx

Is there any known optimization for multiplying a few (3 to 5) bytes (int8) that are known to be 2^x-1 (1, 3, 7...)

This is in the context of multiplying arrays of bytes many, many times with (2^x-1)/2^x. The division is trivial (adding exponents for a shift right) but the numerator is a bit troublesome.

Also, the exponents x are only in 1..31 and the sum of all is always less than 32.

```
// In reality there are 16 of these (i.e. a[16], b[16], c[16])
// ( a + b + c ) < 32
char  a = 2;
char  b = 16;
char  c = 8;

// Ratio/scale, there are 16 of these (i.e. r[16])
// It might work storing in log2 and using int8 or int16
// with fixed point approximation
<x?>  r = ( a - 1 ) * ( b - 1 ) * ( c - 1 ) / ( a * b * c );

// Big original value, just one
int   v = 1234567890;
// This might be done by scaling down to log2, too
// it is used for a comparison only
// doesn't need full 32b precission
// This is also 16 values, of course (i.e. rv[16])
int  rv = v * r;
```

Comment: Could you reword this a bit, I have no idea what you're doing. Something about bytes and multiplying them by some weird fraction, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me to do with bytes. If you can write it in C in scalar code it'll be easier to make an equivalent AVX version.

Comment: @harold done. I tried to make it as elemental as possible.

Comment: As of this writing, the code is still too skeletal to know what optimizations might be appropriate. For example, is the type of 'r' an integral type, so that it's integer division? Or a floating point type? I'd like to see something that would pass a unit test, so that I know what would constitute a correct answer. You've gone down the optimization route to focus on one particular focus, but it may be that the best way to approach it lies elsewhere. Just can't tell without a knowing exactly what you're trying to calculate.

Comment: @eh9 I left it open on purpose, it can be fixed point int16 or int8, or it can be something else altogether (one example could be using one int8 for numerator and another for denominator). As long as it can be processed with vectorization I'm quite open to ideas.

Comment: @alecco OK, you answered one minor specific question I raised, but there's still a need to write down an entire algorithm. The way it's written right now, the expression '(a-1)/a', when computed with integer division, is always zero, which I suspect doesn't give you the answer you want. Suggestion: write what you want down in some bignum/etc. library, or just compute an (non-implementable) algorithm with real numbers to act as a specification.

Comment: How is that division by zero when a >= 2?

Comment: Not "division by zero". *Result* will always be zero.

Comment: Of course, it's a fraction within (0;1] ! That's the whole point, finding a fraction. I even call r ratio. I even explicitly ask, at the very beginning, the problem part is the numerator. Again below I say it's OK to keep numerator and denominator separately.

Comment: N*(2^x-1) == N<<x - N .... Clang does this for constants maybe gcc too

Comment: @alecco I asked for a full algorithm is to know exactly what function you want computed, including what accuracy you need. I can't put LaTeX notation in comments, so being precise is a bit difficult. Here goes. There's a unique integer which is the the integer floor of the rational number equal to the "big original" times the product of the numerators divided by the product of the denominators. If you need that exact number, that's different than getting approximately that number. Do the rational multiplication incrementally, you'll generally get a number lower than that one. What do you need?

Comment: @eh9: If I've understood the question correctly then the final fraction is always less than one, i.e. (x²-1)/x² < 1 => floor(Π (x(i)²-1)/x(i)²) = 0. A worked example with input and expected output value certainly would help clear up some of the confusion.

Comment: @alecco There's another ambiguity in the specification that affects the proper optimization. You say "multiplying arrays of bytes ...". Are the multipliers the _same_ for each element, or does each element get its own multipliers? Are the always 16 multipliers for each element, or was that just an example? How many elements are in the array, that is, is it significantly more than 16?

Comment: Are we lucky enough that the 16 elements all have different values? There's a pretty trivial way to reduce this if the values are mutually exclusive, but I have a feeling that's not the case. Not knowing your application I figure it's worth it to ask.

Comment: @Katie no luck, but good idea. bits...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frankly this function is a poor fit for the AVX instruction set, which lacks integer operations. Straightforward integer left-shifts as provided by SSE2 or AVX2 would almost certainly be the fastest approach. However judging by your comment to Aleksander Z.'s answer I gather you are looking to evaluate alternative approaches.

Forcing this problem onto the AVX unit requires us to get creative with the [IEEE-754 representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Representation_of_numbers) of numbers. Through unaligned loads and bitwise masking we can shuffle the individual byte values into the topmost byte of the 32-bit floats, where the exponent defining the 2^n power of the number lies.

This nearly gets us the desired power function that except we're missing least-significant bit of the exponent field and need to use a square root to adjust it down. Similarly we also need to set the exponent bias through multiplication.

Anyway, take a look at code below for details as there's little point in repeating the comments verbatim here. Beware that the unaligned read (but ignore) up to three bytes *before* the array so please add padding as necessary. Also note that the result words are interleaved, with the result1 storing bytes {0,4,8,12,..} and so forth.

Oh, and obviously the results will be approximations what with floating-point arithmetic being used.

```
void compute(const unsigned char (*ptr)[32], size_t len) {
    const __m256 mask = _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_set1_epi32(0x3F000000U));
    const __m256 normalize = _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_set1_epi32(0x7F000000U));
    const __m256 offset = _mm256_set1_ps(1);

    __m256 result1 = _mm256_set1_ps(1);
    __m256 result2 = _mm256_set1_ps(1);
    __m256 result3 = _mm256_set1_ps(1);
    __m256 result4 = _mm256_set1_ps(1);

    do {
        // Mask out every forth byte into a separate variable using unaligned
        // loads to simulate 8-to-32 bit integer unpacking
        __m256 real1 = _mm256_loadu_ps((const float *) &ptr[0][-3]); 
        __m256 real2 = _mm256_loadu_ps((const float *) &ptr[0][-2]);
        __m256 real3 = _mm256_loadu_ps((const float *) &ptr[0][-1]);
        __m256 real4 = _mm256_loadu_ps((const float *) &ptr[0][-0]);
        real1 = _mm256_and_ps(real1, mask);
        real2 = _mm256_and_ps(real2, mask);
        real3 = _mm256_and_ps(real3, mask);
        real4 = _mm256_and_ps(real4, mask);
        // The binary values are 2^2x * 2^-BIAS once the masked-once top bytes
        // are interpreted as IEEE-754 floating-point exponent bytes.
        // Unfortunately we are overshooting the exponent field by one bit,
        // hence the doubled exponents. Anyway, let's at least multiply the
        // bias away
        real1 = _mm256_mul_ps(real1, normalize);
        real2 = _mm256_mul_ps(real2, normalize);
        real3 = _mm256_mul_ps(real3, normalize);
        real4 = _mm256_mul_ps(real4, normalize);
        // Use a fast aproximate reciprocal square root to halve the exponent,
        // yielding ~1/2^x.
        // You'd think this case of the reciprocal lookup table would be
        // precise, yet it seems not to be. Perhaps twiddling the rounding
        // mode or biasing the values may make it so.
        real1 = _mm256_rsqrt_ps(real1);
        real2 = _mm256_rsqrt_ps(real2);
        real3 = _mm256_rsqrt_ps(real3);
        real4 = _mm256_rsqrt_ps(real4);
        // Compute (2^x-1)/2^x as 1-1/2^x
        real1 = _mm256_sub_ps(offset, real1);
        real2 = _mm256_sub_ps(offset, real2);
        real3 = _mm256_sub_ps(offset, real3);
        real4 = _mm256_sub_ps(offset, real4);
        // Finally multiply the running products
        result1 = _mm256_mul_ps(result1, real1);
        result2 = _mm256_mul_ps(result2, real2);
        result3 = _mm256_mul_ps(result3, real3);
        result4 = _mm256_mul_ps(result4, real4);
    } while(++ptr, --len);

    /*
     * Do something useful with result1..4 here
     */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider float hacking. Good stuff!

Comment: It might not be what I wanted but you gave the best answer, so have the 100 bounty and thank you a lot for your time. This is cool and I might use it somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

As usual, the question asks to optimize a solution, instead of advice on how to solve the original problem. This is annoying.

There are only 32 unique multipliers *m<sub>x</sub>* used:

> *m*<sub>0</sub> = (2<sup>0</sup>-1)/2<sup>0</sup> = 0/1 = 0 
>   *m*<sub>1</sub> = (2<sup>1</sup>-1)/2<sup>1</sup> = 1/2 = 0.5 
>   *m*<sub>2</sub> = (2<sup>2</sup>-1)/2<sup>2</sup> = 3/4 = 0.75 
>   *m*<sub>3</sub> = (2<sup>3</sup>-1)/2<sup>3</sup> = 7/8 = 0.875 
>   *m*<sub>4</sub> = (2<sup>4</sup>-1)/2<sup>4</sup> = 15/16 = 0.9375 
>   *m*<sub>5</sub> = (2<sup>5</sup>-1)/2<sup>5</sup> = 31/32 = 0.96875 
>   *m*<sub>6</sub> = (2<sup>6</sup>-1)/2<sup>6</sup> = 63/64 = 0.984375 
>   *m*<sub>7</sub> = (2<sup>7</sup>-1)/2<sup>7</sup> = 127/128 = 0.9921875 
>   *m*<sub>8</sub> = (2<sup>8</sup>-1)/2<sup>8</sup> = 255/256 = 0.99609375 
>   *m*<sub>9</sub> = (2<sup>9</sup>-1)/2<sup>9</sup> = 511/512 = 0.998046875 
>   *m*<sub>10</sub> = (2<sup>10</sup>-1)/2<sup>10</sup> = 1023/1024 = 0.9990234375 
>   *m*<sub>11</sub> = (2<sup>11</sup>-1)/2<sup>11</sup> = 2047/2048 = 0.99951171875 
>   *m*<sub>12</sub> = (2<sup>12</sup>-1)/2<sup>12</sup> = 4095/4096 = 0.999755859375 
>   *m*<sub>13</sub> = (2<sup>13</sup>-1)/2<sup>13</sup> = 8191/8192 = 0.9998779296875 
>   *m*<sub>14</sub> = (2<sup>14</sup>-1)/2<sup>14</sup> = 16383/16384 = 0.99993896484375 
>   *m*<sub>15</sub> = (2<sup>15</sup>-1)/2<sup>15</sup> = 32767/32768 = 0.999969482421875 
>   *m*<sub>16</sub> = (2<sup>16</sup>-1)/2<sup>16</sup> = 65535/65536 = 0.9999847412109375 
>   *m*<sub>17</sub> = (2<sup>17</sup>-1)/2<sup>17</sup> = 131071/131072 = 0.99999237060546875 
>   *m*<sub>18</sub> = (2<sup>18</sup>-1)/2<sup>18</sup> = 262143/262144 = 0.999996185302734375 
>   *m*<sub>19</sub> = (2<sup>19</sup>-1)/2<sup>19</sup> = 524287/524288 = 0.9999980926513671875 
>   *m*<sub>20</sub> = (2<sup>20</sup>-1)/2<sup>20</sup> = 1048575/1048576 = 0.99999904632568359375 
>   *m*<sub>21</sub> = (2<sup>21</sup>-1)/2<sup>21</sup> = 2097151/2097152 = 0.999999523162841796875 
>   *m*<sub>22</sub> = (2<sup>22</sup>-1)/2<sup>22</sup> = 4194303/4194304 = 0.9999997615814208984375 
>   *m*<sub>23</sub> = (2<sup>23</sup>-1)/2<sup>23</sup> = 8388607/8388608 = 0.99999988079071044921875 
>   *m*<sub>24</sub> = (2<sup>24</sup>-1)/2<sup>24</sup> = 16777215/16777216 = 0.999999940395355224609375 
>   *m*<sub>25</sub> = (2<sup>25</sup>-1)/2<sup>25</sup> = 33554431/33554432 = 0.9999999701976776123046875 
>   *m*<sub>26</sub> = (2<sup>26</sup>-1)/2<sup>26</sup> = 67108863/67108864 = 0.99999998509883880615234375 
>   *m*<sub>27</sub> = (2<sup>27</sup>-1)/2<sup>27</sup> = 134217727/134217728 = 0.999999992549419403076171875 
>   *m*<sub>28</sub> = (2<sup>28</sup>-1)/2<sup>28</sup> = 268435455/268435456 = 0.9999999962747097015380859375 
>   *m*<sub>29</sub> = (2<sup>29</sup>-1)/2<sup>29</sup> = 536870911/536870912 = 0.99999999813735485076904296875 
>   *m*<sub>30</sub> = (2<sup>30</sup>-1)/2<sup>30</sup> = 1073741823/1073741824 = 0.999999999068677425384521484375 
>   *m*<sub>31</sub> = (2<sup>31</sup>-1)/2<sup>31</sup> = 2147483647/2147483648 = 0.9999999995343387126922607421875

The decimal values above are all exact.

Three to five multipliers (in the above table) are multiplied together, and finally with a "big number", to get the final result.

A trivial look-up table would require 32 entries. A look-up table that contains the products of two multipliers would require 32<sup>2</sup> = 1,024 entries. A look-up table that contains the products of three multipliers would require 32<sup>3</sup> = 32,768 entries. The four-multiplier one would require 1,048,576 entries, and is typically too large to be cache-efficient on current processors.

With [Binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) the first 25 entries (*m*<sub>0</sub> to *m*<sub>24</sub>, inclusive) are exact, but the last seven (*m*<sub>25</sub> to *m*<sub>31</sub>, inclusive) cannot be represented, and evaluate to 1. Thus, if each *x* is limited to range [0, 24], then binary32 coefficients would suffice. Also, the "big number" to be multiplied by the compound coefficient would only have seven or so significant digits.

With [Binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), the multipliers would be exact, and "big number" would have at least 17 significant digits.

SSE vectors (__m128) hold four Binary32 floating-point numbers, and AVX vectors (__m256) eight; two and four Binary64, respectively. If there are 16 "big numbers" to calculate, this means two, four, or eight vector words, depending on architecture and format.

Let's assume you use Binary64 instead, with a aligned tables two (`mul2[32][32]`) and three (`mul3[32][32][32]`) multiplier products. The overall pseudocode to calculate 16 "big numbers" in a vector would boil down to

1. Convert big numbers to Binary64 vectors, say *num*.
2. Pack big number final coefficients into vectors:

   If a number has three multipliers *a*,*b*,*c*, load
    
    *c1* = mul3[*a*][*b*][*c*]
    
    *c2* = 1.0

   If a number has four multipliers *a*,*b*,*c*, *d*, load
    
    *c1* = mul2[*a*][*b*]
    
    *c2* = mul2[*c*][*d*]

   If a number has five multipliers *a*,*b*,*c*, *d*, *e*, load
    
    *c1* = mul3[*a*][*b*][*c*]
    
    *c2* = mul2[*d*][*e*]
3. Calculate (vector multiply)

   *result* = *num* · *c1* · *c2*
4. Round to nearest integer if desired.

   If all *num* were nonnegative, just add 0.5 to each *result*, so that the following truncation rounds correctly.
5. Truncate and store *result* as 32-bit or 64-bit integers.

Note that because of the table lookups, you only need at most two multiplications -- and these are vector multiplications. The table lookup is slightly worrisome, as it has to be done for each component separately.

Many current processors have two ALUs per core, so unrolling and interleaving the above so that you operate on two (or more) different vector words at a time often yields a significant improvement to simply vectorizing a calculation. This also means that having more data than can fit in a single vector word is a good thing; it allows better overall performance.

The same approach would obviously work with Binary32, too.

Since the table lookup is likely another bottleneck, interleaving the entire operation so that you start processing another vector word pair at the lookup stage when doing the vector multiplication, should let you squeeze everything out of the CPU, albeit the resulting code is a bit more complex to understand.

If you do take this route, I warmly recommend you add your full pseudocode description as a comment to the function that does it. Helps a lot with the code maintenance later.

Answer (score 1):

isn't it as simple as:

```
a * (2^x - 1) = (a << x) - a
```

Comment: That's just the first multiplication. Onwards it's:  a * (2^x0 - 1) * (2^x1 - 1) * ....   / I just made it more clear (just using byteS might be have sounded that it's only 2 bytes/numbers)

Comment: Can't you apply it recursively, that is: b = (a << x0) - a; c = (b << x1) - b? I haven't ever been that good in math :( and for now I don't see other solution.

Comment: No AVX byte shift. Moving all numbers to int32 to do it this way is why I asked for an optimization. The values are interesting in this case because of the 2^x-1 in binary is all ones. But I'm not clever enough to find a bit hack after a day banging my head against it :)

Comment: Maybe you should rather ask on math.stackexchange.com ;)

Comment: Thanks, but this is more like an algorithmic problem over defined types, and optimization. They deal with symbolic math. I did spend quite a while on WolframAlpha and playing with logarithm identities before asking here.

Comment: @alecco: avx2 has variable-count shifts (where the count is different for each element: `VPSLLVD`, but the minimum element size is 32bits.  SSE and AVX1 don't have variable-count shifts at all (`psllw` with the count in an xmm register uses the low 8bits of the count register for all elements).  Anyway, unpacking 8->32 and then back isn't too bad, except that `pmovzx` doesn't work in-lane the same way `punpck/packus` do.

Answer (score 1):

All I am seeing is that (a bit contrary to your last calculation):

```
(2^a-1)(2^b-1)(2^c-1)=2^(a+b+c)-2^(a+b)-2^(b+c)-2^(a+c)
                              + 2^a + 2^b + 2^c - 1
```

Note that all terms in the expansion will be powers of two, with all exponents < 32 according to your constraint. Of course all 32 of those possible terms can be "precomputed". And then it is a matter of just summing up 2^j of such terms (3 <= j <= 5 by your constraint). By my count, for the j=3 case above, that's 4 adds for the abc's, 7 "lookups", and 7 adds for the terms. I have no idea if that is an improvement over just doing the 3 "lookups" (of 2^x-1) and 2 multiplies (biting the bullet) for you...

Also to note: multiplying anything by a factor `2^y-1` can be done by `(y-1)` shifts and `(y-1)` adds. Assuming exponents `a,b,c,d,e`, with `a` being the largest, that's `(b+c+d+e-4)` shifts and `(b+c+d+e-4)` adds (starting with `2^a-1`).

Comment: On the first part, it's not an expansion. It's the steps of the original multiplication x*(a-1)*(b-1)*(c-1), for simplicity, starting with 1: let x = 1; x = 2*x - x; x = 16*x-x; x = 8*x - x; (and so on...)

Comment: Second part, this is for vectors of 16 elements. Even combining lookups like nwellnhof suggested, it's quite slow and not vectorized. Also you are thinking the case of 3 and not the case of 4 and 5.

Comment: I'm not following I guess. `(a-1)*(b-1)*(c-1)=abc-ab-bc-ac+a+b+c-1`

Comment: There seems to be some confusion between abc being exponents or not, i.e. your 2^abc above where they are, or your code where they are not.

Comment: Yes, the last bit of code was wrong (also the c on the left was not the c on the right, of course). Fixed. It got bad because I'm tired of re-editing over and over the question to fit every single person asking for clarification. People who never answered or asked a single question on SIMD/SSE/AVX/AVX2 or anything like that. Wish I could delete this question now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a simple precomputed lookup table? If I understand your question correctly, `x0`, `x1`, and `x2` are always between 1 and 31 and can be stored in five bits, so there are only `2^15 = 32768` combinations. The means that `r` can be computed with a couple of bit shifts and bitwise ORs to compute an index and single lookup in a rather small table.

This table lookup can't be vectorized, of course.

Comment: Yes, but that's 16 table lookups per iteration, then combine all those in a vector to multiply. And the table wouldn't fit in L1 unless it was just 8 bit entries (error quite big).

Comment: Also, that's just for the basic case of 3, the question is for 3 to 5. The later case is 2^25.

Comment: @alecco: The code in your question suggests that all the values are already powers of two, and they fit in bytes. So the only possible values are: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128. It means that there are 8^5 = 32K possibilities for five input values.
You can take all five bytes as a single uint64_t value (zero-padded) and use trivial perfect hash function to get index not greater than 64K. Then simply fetch the precomputed ratio in any form you want.

Comment: @stgatilov This is for vectors of 16 elements, so it would be 16 lookups in a table that doesn't fit in L1. I don't get what you mean by hashing, but table lookup was the first thing I tried without luck.